# Is there an “expiration date” related to how long a living creature can be frozen in Carbonite and then safely revived?

Tags: star-wars, plot-device

After asking [this other question about Han Solo’s personal experience of being frozen in Carbonite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269002/14850), I was wondering: Is there the equivalent of an “expiration date” when it comes to a living creature being frozen in Carbonite?

In the case of Han Solo hanging as a trophy in Jabba’s palace, Jabba didn’t trust care if Han Solo was alive or dead, right? Yeah, maybe Boba Fett would have gotten less of a reward if Han Solo was dead. But Jabba just wanted an actual trophy to display regardless.

But Han Solo’s friends showed up within a relatively short time between the events of [*The Empire Strikes Back*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back) (1980) and [*Return of the Jedi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi) (1983) and “unfroze” him, thus saving him from being frozen and in suspended animation; aka: imprisonment.

What if that didn’t happen? What if years, and even decades, passed… What would have happened?

- Would an undamaged Han Solo from [*The Empire Strikes Back*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back) (1980) be freed from imprisonment?
- Or would there simply be a cadaver or pile of gelatenous goo and bones left behind?

[image: Han Solo frozen in Carbonite and hanging as a trophy in Jabba’s palace.]

---

***Looking for in-universe, canonical explanations; not armchair speculation and theories. If none (currently) exist, legends explanation would suffice. Regardless, please provide references and context.***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In canon, freezing a subject in carbonite for very extensive periods (even hundreds of years) appears to be perfectly feasible. The discovery of carbonite-freezing apparently did away with the need for [generational ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_ship) to explore the galaxy until the discovery of hyperspace did away with the need to freeze people.

> The peculiar stasis qualities of carbonite have been known in the
> galaxy for centuries, as **ancient sleeper ships that expanded the
> pre-Republic borders relied upon extended hibernation to keep the crew
> alive as they traveled across unfathomable distances. The use of
> carbonite for organic hibernation faded away as hyperdrives did away
> with the need for such lengthy voyages,** and bio-entropic field
> generators became the norm in medical applications. Carbon freezing
> thus became the standard for industrial applications, such as the
> freezing of coaxium, tibanna, and other volatile substances for
> transport. With some modifications, however, these carbon-freezing
> chambers could be equipped to entrap living cargo, subjecting them to
> a painful stasis that has been described as “a big wide- awake
> nothing." Imperials, bounty hunters, and some gangsters have been
> known to use carbonite in this crude but effective way. The earliest
> known trophies of this variety date back to the ancient Krath that
> conquered the carbonite mines of the Empress Teta system, thousands of
> years ago in the galaxy's dark past.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Scum and Villainy: Case Files on the Galaxy's Most Notorious](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Scum_and_Villainy:_Case_Files_on_the_Galaxy%27s_Most_Notorious)</sup></sub>

Comment: If it was well known for centuries pre republic, then why did C3P0 not know if Han would survive the freezing process or not?  (I assume it was C3P0, I couldn't recognise him without his red arm)